# Icon not appearing in shinydashboardPlus::boxDropdown()

Tags: r, shiny, icons, font-awesome

I was trying to implement the below icon into the shiny app.

[image]

But the icon is appearing. I was trying with the below shiny code.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyApp(fluidPage(    
  
  # Give the page a title
  titlePanel("Telephones by region"),
  
  # Generate a row with a sidebar
  sidebarLayout(      
    
    # Define the sidebar with one input
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("region", "Region:", 
                  choices=colnames(WorldPhones)),
      hr(),
      helpText("Data from AT&T (1961) The World's Telephones.")
    ),
    
    # Create a spot for the barplot
    mainPanel(
      shinydashboardPlus::box(
        # Analysis UI Module function and arguments from JSON file
        plotOutput("phonePlot"),
        title = "Hi!",
        width = 12,
        closable = TRUE,
        collapsible = TRUE,
        dropdownMenu = shinydashboardPlus::boxDropdown(
          shinydashboardPlus::boxDropdownItem("Hi!"),
          shinydashboardPlus::boxDropdownItem("Hello!"),
          icon = icon("circle-ellipsis")
        )
      ) 
    )
    
  )
),

# Define a server for the Shiny app
function(input, output) {
  
  # Fill in the spot we created for a plot
  output$phonePlot <- renderPlot({
    
    # Render a barplot
    barplot(WorldPhones[,input$region]*1000, 
            main=input$region,
            ylab="Number of Telephones",
            xlab="Year")
  })
})
```

I am trying with 'circle-ellipsis' icon, it is also not working with the only 'ellipsis' icon. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: When I run this code I have the following warning: `This Font Awesome icon ('circle-ellipsis') does not exist: * if providing a custom "html_dependency" these "name" checks can  be deactivated with "verify_fa = FALSE"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `icon("ellipsis-h")` instead. `shiny::icon` supports icons from FontAwesome versions 4 and 5. You can search for these icons here:

- v4: https://fontawesome.com/v4/icons/
- v5: https://fontawesome.com/v5/search?q=ellipsis